# Imagebase error in Delphi EXE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am writing an EXE wrapper (sort of packer) to protect my EXE and in turn it will get executed directly into memory. The below sample shows executing Calculator into memory.

```
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  FS := TFileStream.Create('calc.exe', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
  SetLength(eu, FS.Size);
  FS.Read(eu[0], FS.Size);
  FS.Free;
  SInfo.cb := Sizeof(TStartupInfo);
  CreateProcess(nil, Pchar(paramstr(0)), nil, nil, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, nil,
    nil, SInfo, PInfo);
  IDH := @eu[0];
  INH := @eu[IDH^._lfanew];
  imgbase := DWORD(VirtualAllocEx(PInfo.hProcess,
    Ptr(INH^.OptionalHeader.ImageBase), INH^.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage,
    MEM_COMMIT or MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE));
  ShowMessage(IntToHex(imgbase, 8));
  WriteProcessMemory(PInfo.hProcess, Ptr(imgbase), @eu[0],
    INH^.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, SIZE_T(btsIO));
  for i := 0 to INH^.FileHeader.NumberOfSections - 1 do
  begin
    ISH := @eu[IDH^._lfanew + Sizeof(TImageNtHeaders) + i *
      Sizeof(TImageSectionHeader)];
    WriteProcessMemory(PInfo.hProcess, Ptr(imgbase + ISH^.VirtualAddress),
      @eu[ISH^.PointerToRawData], ISH^.SizeOfRawData, SIZE_T(btsIO));
  end;
  CONT.ContextFlags := CONTEXT_FULL;
  GetThreadContext(PInfo.hThread, CONT);
  CONT.Eax := imgbase + INH^.OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
  WriteProcessMemory(PInfo.hProcess, Ptr(CONT.Ebx + 8), @imgbase, 4,
    SIZE_T(btsIO));
  ShowMessage('Press ok on ENTER');
  SetThreadContext(PInfo.hThread, CONT);
  ResumeThread(PInfo.hThread);
  CloseHandle(PInfo.hThread);
  CloseHandle(PInfo.hProcess);
end;
```

I changed the code to include an extra resource. At this point, to my surprise, the Imagebase becomes zero!

```
    {$R *.dfm}
    {$R test.res}  //extra resourse added

        procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
        var
          i: Integer;
        begin
          FS := TFileStream.Create('calc.exe', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
          SetLength(eu, FS.Size);
          FS.Read(eu[0], FS.Size);
          FS.Free;
          SInfo.cb := Sizeof(TStartupInfo);
          CreateProcess(nil, Pchar(paramstr(0)), nil, nil, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, nil,
            nil, SInfo, PInfo);
          IDH := @eu[0];
          INH := @eu[IDH^._lfanew];
          imgbase := DWORD(VirtualAllocEx(PInfo.hProcess,
            Ptr(INH^.OptionalHeader.ImageBase), INH^.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage,
            MEM_COMMIT or MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE));
          ShowMessage(IntToHex(imgbase, 8));
.....
.....
```

- In the first example, i got Imagebase = 01000000 (code works perfectly)
- In the second example (where I added an extra resourse to my project) I am getting Imagebase = 00000000  (Code fails..)

Can Anyone please explain me why it is so..?

Comment: You are aware that executing from memory is not supported?

Comment: Thanks David for your comment.
As far as I know it is legal and allowed. Look at way how UPX is executing compressed exe.. First, the original code is being decompressed into memory and then it gets executed. The same is true for most of the famous exe packers. ASPack also does the same, however, it has much better encryption and protection mechanism against crackers than what we have in UPX. Here we are not trying to execute a malicious code, instead we are trying to create a legal wrapper which works exactly same as UPX or ASPack. Hope this clarifies the scenario in a better way.

Comment: Well, my point is just that MS does not support loading images from memory and code that does so is liable to break in the face of future releases or even OS updates. I understand why you want to do this I just wanted to make sure you knew that it was not supported to do it.

Comment: You may wish to see what `GetLastError` returns, but perhaps passing in null as second param to `VirtualAllocEx` might resolve the problem.

Comment: Ignore David Heffernan, it is supported.

Comment: @Marcus: I tired your code and it gives an Imagebase 1C0000. But still the code doesn't work. I am hitting, "The application was unable to start correctly(0x0000018)"

Comment: @user can you point to documentation to back this statement?

Comment: @DavidHef, ofc i [can](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Process/NtCreateProcess.html).

Comment: @user539484 That's the native API, the use of which is not supported. I think you'd need to point to something provided by MS in order to back up your claim.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, you are "debunking" that basing solely on its URL, arent you? :-) I have strong feeling what i had such quasidiscussion before. I think next step will be ingnoring an advice to consult Nebbet/Solomon :-) Ugh, well, really, it works. Are we arguing on the meaning of "supported" term? :-)

Comment: @user539484 Clearly execute from memory code can be made to work fine with all current versions of Windows. My point is that the APIs required to do so are not supported in the sense that future versions of Windows are quite at liberty to break them. What's more, in order to be able to call `NtCreateProcess` you need to do reimplement the private implementation details of the loader. We quite possibly are arguing about what each other means by supported.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, i'd call that not-so-private, since it is exposed in the export dir. Yes, they do not guarantee its consistent behavior across the version. But, hell, no one is safe from that, being *public* and *documented* function doesnt offer an absolute protection against alteration

Comment: @user That's true. Of course MS bend over backwards to keep the win32 API compatible through OS changes but you can expect the native API to be more subject to change. I'm intrigued by you pointing out `NtCreateProcess`. How would you actually drive that in practice? You'd need to do a lot of the work of the loader. How would you recommend doing that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, sure thing, the more common API is, the more resilent software sitting on its top will be (Yoda approves this sentence :). Look at the function's arguments: it provides process creation from memory, rather than standard way - from the disk file.

Comment: @user539484 Yes, but all the fixups and so on that the loader does need to be handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pure luck you've got it working the first time round: `lpStartupInfo` is an *in* parameter to `CreateProcess`, you have to initialize its members:

```
..
FillChar(SInfo, SizeOf(SInfo), 0);
SInfo.cb := Sizeof(TStartupInfo);
CreateProcess(...
..
```

Comment: Similarly, what is the return value of createprocess? Does the winapi report success?